# Why are there 2 sources for power levels/skills in My Hero Academia, the Ultra Archive, and the Ultra Analysis?

Tags: my-hero-academia

The My Hero Academia wikia list 2 sources for characters power levels/skills, the Ultra Archive and the Ultra Analysis. They have different figures for the same skills of the same characters. Why are there 2 sources for power levels/skills in My Hero Academia, the Ultra Archive, and the Ultra Analysis? Is one of them more canon or official than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The books you are referring to are **both official character books**. *My Hero Academia Official Character Book Ultra Archive* is the first book and was released back in 2016. *My Hero Academia Official Character Book 2 Ultra Analysis* is the second book released this year in 2019.

I would say there are two books to update the information we have on new heroes, villains and/or characters. Looking at their wiki pages, ([Ultra Archive](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/My_Hero_Academia_Official_Character_Book_Ultra_Archive), [Ultra Analysis](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/My_Hero_Academia_Official_Character_Book_2_Ultra_Analysis)) one can see that **the second book has new heroes/villains that were not present in the first character guide book**.